# Nodejs and module cache invalidation

Tags: node.js, swagger

I read a lot about module cache invalidation in Nodejs, and still cannot figure it out.
Here's a short example, which I can't get my head around:

```
//a.js
var x=0;
console.log('loaded');
exports.y = function() {};

//b.js
var v1 = require('./a.js');  //displays "loaded"
delete require.cache[require.resolve('a.js')];
var v2 = require('./a.js');  //DOES NOT display "loaded". WHY?
console.log(v1 === v2);  //displays false, so it's a different instance
```

Basically, what I need it that x be a different variable inbetween calls.
Shouldn't the message "loaded" be displayed twice?

Thanks in advance,
Catalin

**UPDATE.**
Basically I need this functionality in swagger (Rest services documentation generator) because I'd like to export more API groups on different url's, and since the only module I have found to do it is swagger-node-express, it is created as a module with modular variables. So I need to somehow invalidate it entirely so as to be able to generate more documentations from the same codebase.

Comment: This behavior is indeed strange, and I couldn't reproduce it; I see `loaded` both times. What version of node are you running? Do you see the same behavior when you use `./a.js` consistently (instead of `a.js`)? What if you export a random number in the module: do you see it change between cache invalidations?

Comment: Tried it and it works for me - I'm on node version 0.10.21

Comment: Solved. It was an error on my part: I was doing cleaning of sub-cache (caching of subfiles) and doing _delete_ on the object returned by require.resolve, instead of on the object.id (which is the actual key, and fullpath filename). _Thanks_